# Store doesn't update after GET

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-admin

After DELETE a resource via a Button I update the same resource with a GET, i get the response with the correct data but the redux store doesn't update (apparently the redux action see no diff), and so the props are not updated.

But when I do a CREATE and then a GET like before (same call) this time the redux store see the diff and update the props.

The resource are the same between the 2 calls (after DELETE or CREATE), and the calls are even the same. Why in one case the redux store see the diff and don't in another case ?

```
crudCreate(`${CAMPAIGNS}/${id}/${LINE_ITEMS}`, data, () =>
  crudGetAll(LINE_ITEMS, {}, { campaignId: id }, 1000, () => this.displayModal()),
);

crudDelete(LINE_ITEMS, lineItem.id, { id }, lineItem, () =>
   crudGetAll(LINE_ITEMS, {}, { campaignId: id }, 1000, ({ payload: { data } }) =>
    this.updateLineItems(data),
   ),
);
```

I don't any error on Redux debugger or on Console. I have a custom DataProvider, in that case it only redirect for the good routes

```
case LINE_ITEMS: {
     if (type === 'DELETE') {
      return { urn: `${apiUrl}/campaigns/${filter.id}/${resource.toLowerCase()}/${id}` };
      }
     if (filter) {
      if ('campaignId' in filter) {
       return {
        urn: `${apiUrl}/campaigns/${filter.campaignId}/${resource.toLowerCase()}`,
         filter: {
          ...filter,
          campaignId: undefined,
         },
        };
       }
      }
      return {
       urn: `${apiUrl}/campaigns/${id.campaignId}/${resource.toLowerCase()}/${data.lineItemId}`,
      };
     }
```

And I only use the reducer from react-admin, here my `index.js`:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { crudDelete, crudGetAll, translate } from 'react-admin';
    export default connect(
      state => ({
        lineItems: Object.values(state.admin.resources.lineItems.data) || {},
        swordData: Object.values(state.admin.resources.sword.data),
      }),
      { crudDelete, crudGetAll },
    )(withRouter(WithPermissions(translate(MyComponent))));
```

Does anybody have an idea? Thanks for your help

Comment: are you creating a custom `dataprovider`?

Comment: can you show your reducer and `crudGetAll`? How do you actually store the data in reducer?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have edited my question